# Creation/Handling of lists of Monad.State's?

Tags: haskell, state

I'm just in the process of learning haskell and I am sure that an elegant solution to the following problem exists.
Given a function f that returns a stateful computation

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> a -> State [a] a
f x y = modify ((2*x):) >> return (x+y)   -- state and value are modified based on the passed values
```

I am looking for the cleanest way to generate multiple `State`'s from a given one recursively (as shown below). One solution I came up with is the following

```
g :: (Num a) => [a] -> (a, [a]) -> [(a,[a])]
g [] _ = []
g (x:xs) aa@(a,b) = (new : next)
    where new = runState (f x a) b   -- here the old value a is required!
          next = g xs aa
```

but I guess something like

```
g :: [a] -> [State [a] a]
```

should be possible and cleaner? I didn't succeed trying this and get errors from StateT that I can't figure out.

Thank you!

*Background:* The code is a simplification of parts of a graph generator I am writing, where the state is the current adjacency vector. For each node, several edges may be created and therefore multiple state is required representing the different (partial) graphs.

*Edit*: (Try of) A description in words of the above function `g x (y, s)` in words:

For a given list of values `x`, a single value `y` and a state `s`, compute recursively for each `x_i` in `x` a new value and state from `(y,s)` given by the stateful computation `f x_i y`  and return the result as a list.

*Edit 2*: Example output:

```
 g [1,2,3] (4,[2,3,4]) == [(5,[10,2,3,4]),(6,[12,2,3,4]),(7,[14,2,3,4])]
```

Comment: Well written question! But can you please give more of a specification for `g`? Can you describe it in words? This is not only for us to be able to answer your question, to summarize behavior is also invaluable for learning.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the code of `g` matches what you said you want. What is the `a` in the `(a,b)` tuple given to `g`? Why does it not exist in the second definition of `g`?

Comment: @Tarrasch: Please see my edit where I've tried to describe the function `g`.

Comment: @Peaker: The tuple `(a,b) :: (a, [a])` represents a value and a state, and `g` creates new value-state pairs from this one. Do you mean `g :: [a] -> [State [a] a]` by second definition? Maybe this is nonsense and my main question. But I though that because `State a b = (a -> (b,a))` no additional parameter is required, as one can give the "starting computation" to `runState`...

Comment: @bbtrb Why don't you apply `h` to the list elements outside `g`? It seems like it is orthogonal to the main thing `g` does and serves to confuse about the purpose of `g`. Also, the State type here is just a clumsy representation of a function here, apparently, so `f` should just be: `a -> [a] -> (a, [a])`.

Comment: @Peaker: you are right, I'll remove `h` completely and give an additional argument to `f`. Wait, this doesn't make much sense either... now you've got me confused

Comment: @bbtrb The idea is that instead of `g` transforming each value in the list before using it -- you can map the list to transform it all once before applying `g` altogether. Then `g` doesn't have to worry about calling `h` or its `a` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some iterative changes to your `g` function. I hope this is what you were looking for, because I am not sure I fully understand what you tried to achieve:

Your original g:

```
g :: Num a => [a] -> a -> [a] -> [(a,[a])]
g [] _ _ = []
g (x:xs) a b = new : next
  where
    new = runState (f (h x a)) b   -- here the old value a is required!
    next = g xs a b
```

Points-free:

```
g1 :: Num a => [a] -> a -> [a] -> [(a,[a])]
g1 xs a b = map (($ b) . runState . f . (`h` a)) $ xs
```

Flip for ETA reducability:

```
g2 :: Num a => [a] -> a -> [a] -> [(a,[a])]
g2 b a = map (($ b) . runState . f . (`h` a))
```

Without the `($ b) . runState` application (no need for the extra [a] argument since we don't apply the State computations):

```
g3 :: Num a => a -> [a] -> [State [a] a]
g3 a = map (f . (`h` a))
```

The map there can also be written:

```
map f . map (`h` a)
```

and then you can take the

```
 map (\`h\` a)
```

part out somewhere else.

This gives you something similar to the type you wanted for `g`, and of course changes the semantics (as that type is still unapplied to the input state)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. The steps how you got from `g` to `g3` really helped a lot, too.